# Is it possible make the attachment as a link to download a file in infopth form

Tags: pdf, infopath, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

I have an infopath form where i can attach pdf files. The attachment can be viewed only if i chose download from the attachment icon. I am unable to view the pdf by just clicking on the attachment. How to add this feature so that the user simply clicks on the attachment to download/view the file.

Thanks!

P.S: This is a browser enabled form hosted in my sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007, you can think of storing the file url in a SharePoint list and displaying the links in the Infopath form. This will directly open up the file from the form and even you have the links stored in the list. Please read this [**article**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/abf45653-3959-43b1-b4c2-60d209715845/).

If you are checking this out in SharePoint 2010 - its quite straight forward. [**This**](http://ctp.social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sharepoint2010customization/thread/b2340454-8b37-4b28-a28d-548425674b4d) might help.

Comment: I upload a file via an infopath form which adds the file to the library and displays in a webpart. The file when clicked takes me back to form to download. Is there anyway to directly download the file from sharepoint without having to goto the infopath form?